# aws elastic search http request , error 'The bulk request must be terminated by a newline'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, https, bulk

I have used [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node) to create a bulk http request using a `JSON.stringified(body)` like this:

```
const body = [ { index: { _index: 'image_2', _type: '_doc', _id: 0 } },
{ imageKey: 'test' },
{ index: { _index: 'image_2', _type: '_doc', _id: 1 } },
{ imageKey: 'test2' } ]
```

but I keep getting the error

```
{ statusCode: 400,
body: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\\\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\\\n]"},"status":400}' }
```

I already tried this below and it is not working either:

```
const body = `${JSON.stringified(body)\n}`;
```

any ideas are appreciated :)

here is my `aws elastic search function`:

```
function elasticsearchFetch(elasticsearchDomain, endpointPath, options = {}, region = process.env.AWS_REGION) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { body, method = 'GET' } = options;

    const endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(elasticsearchDomain);
    const request = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint, region);
    request.method = method;
    request.path += endpointPath;
    request.headers.host = elasticsearchDomain;
    if (body) {
      request.body = body;
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      request.headers['Content-Length'] = request.body.length;
    }

    const credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
    const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(request, 'es');
    signer.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date());

    const client = new AWS.HttpClient();
    client.handleRequest(request, null, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => resolve({ statusCode: res.statusCode, body: chunks }));
    }, error => reject(error));
  });
}
```

and here is the code for my lambda function using the above request signer:

```
const elasticsearchFetch = require('rms-library/fetch');
exports.handler = async ({ imageID, bulk, products }) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(products) || !imageID) {
    throw new Error('error in bulk operation');
  }
  const bulkList = [];
  products.forEach((product, i) => {
    bulkList.push({ index: { _index: imageID, _type: '_doc', _id: i } });
    bulkList.push(product);
  });
  bulkList.push('');
  console.log('bulkList', bulkList);
  const result = await elasticsearchFetch.elasticsearch(
    process.env.ELASTIC_SEARCH_DOMAIN,
    '_bulk',
    { method: 'PUT', body: JSON.stringify(bulkList) },
  );
  console.log(result);
};
```

Comment: The newline character needs to be located outside of the `${...}`. And then it still won't work, because bulk doesn't expect a stringified JSON array but each array element on its own line

Comment: @Val yes, it still won't work with your change

Comment: Yes, that's what I said above :-) Please show all the relevant code so we can fix it

Comment: @Val I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all you need to use `POST` instead of `PUT` with the `_bulk` endpoint and the body cannot be a stringified JSON array.

Try like this instead:

```
const result = await elasticsearchFetch.elasticsearch(
  process.env.ELASTIC_SEARCH_DOMAIN,
  '_bulk',
  { method: 'POST', body: bulkList.map(json => {return JSON.stringify(json);}).join('\n') + '\n' },
);
```

Comment: still getting the same error , event tried the `body: JSON.stringify(bulkList.join('\n'))`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've updated my answer. The idea is to stringify each JSON line, then concatenate them with newlines and add a newline at the end. Try again

Comment: Thanks , will try again

Comment: Can you print out the first few lines of the `body` by any chance?

Comment: It seems you're never sending the body, i.e. `request.body = 'body';` should be `request.body = body;` without the single quotes

Comment: ahhhh, I hate myself